# How do I delete a row with trigger when a cells has a value of 0

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, sql-delete, database-trigger

I have a cart table where customers can add, update or remove a product from the cart. Another way to remove an item is by putting the value 0 in the quantity column. I try to use a trigger to delete the row, but it doesn't delete it. How do I fix this?

This is what I tried and doesnt work

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_remove_cart_item
AFTER UPDATE ON cart
for each row
IF NEW.quantity <= 0
THEN
    DELETE FROM cart
    WHERE NEW.quantity <= 0;
END IF;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: in a trigger you can not use delete or update on the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger cannot action the table it was fired upon. So what you ask for basically cannot be done with a trigger.

An alternative would be to use a stored procedure to implement the logic.

Here is an example, that assumes that table `cart` has columns `cart_id`, `item_id` and `quantity`:

```
delimiter //
create procedure update_cart(
    in p_cart_id int,
    in p_item_id int,
    in p_quantity int
)
begin
    if p_quantity > 0 then
        update cart 
        set quantity = p_quantity 
        where cart_id = p_cart_id and item_id = p_item_id;
    else
        delete from cart
        where cart_id = p_cart_id and item_id = p_item_id;  
    end if;
end //
delimiter ;
```

The procedures receives three arguments as input; if the `quantity` is greater than `0`, it `update`s the `cart` table, else it `delete`s the corresponding record.

You can run the procedure with the following code:

```
call update_cart(1, 2, 3);
```

Where `1`, `2`, `3` are, respectively, the `cart_id`, `item_id` and `quantity`.